# How can I remove the orange color from my shoes midsole?

Tags: cleaning, clothing, repair, color

I have a pair of sneakers which are white and one time I put them in a black garbage bag with my other shoes .

After a couple of days I saw orange colored spots and dots on one of my sneakers midsole part .

I tried to clean them with anything that you can imagine but it just doesn't turn white .

Here is a picture of the damage been done to my sneakers :

[image: Trainers with discoloured sole]

[image: Trainers with discoloured sole]

How can I clean them ? If not can I do something else like changing it's midsole completely or cover it up with something white ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a mix of water and bleach at 8:1 ratio.

Put shoes in sink, then pour in the mix until it cover the midsole but not high enough to touch the shoe upper fabric.

Leave overnight, check the next day, rinse off.

*Note: I can see the top edge of your midsole isn't horizontal so I would suggest putting something underneath the shoe so when it is placed in the sink, the top edge of the midsole is horizontal and that way you can bleach the whole midsole in one go.

*Caution: I have not done this before myself however, this technique is sometimes used to re-whiten yellowed plastics. So I cannot guarantee this will work perfectly or won't damage the shoe in some way. Maybe test with an old shoe in the water/bleach mix for 24hrs just to make sure not damage occurs. I don't think there will be so its up to you.

Comment: Caution indeed: the chlorine in bleach can attack composite materials.